# 307 redirect in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, redirect, http-request, magento2.4.5p1

How could I implement in Magento 2 a http 307 redirect. I would like if possible use Magento methods/framework not phps.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect with 307 response from the controller then use the below code:

```
/**
 * @var $resultRedirect \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
 */
$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
$resultRedirect->setHttpResponseCode(307);
return $resultRedirect->setPath('contact/index/index');
```

Here `$this->resultRedirectFactory` is instance/object of `\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory`